# Redirected URL don’t update the content after flushing cache

Tags: wordpress, redirect

We use WordPress to serve app-ads.txt to the monetization networks we work with. It is located at the root folder where index.php is also located. Also we use redirection to forward the urls which contains www to the url which doesnt have the www part. .htaccess file is below. But after updating the content of ads.txt and flushing the cache to apply the changes immediately, we can see the changes only for the non www version of our site, www version of our site update the content after 2-3 days.

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.oursiteurl\.com\.tr$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^9k5\.198\.oursiteurl\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN FRedirect_ErrorDocument
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN FRedirect_ErrorDocument" and "END FRedirect_ErrorDocument" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
# END FRedirect_ErrorDocument
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use cloudflare, purge custom cache yoururl.com/ads.txt
and test it yoururl.com/ads.txt?asdfgh